# Coordinating Floating-Action Button behaviour across Child Fragments/Activities

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, floating-action-button

I have an issue coordinating the behaviour of a Floating Action Button in an Activity with its children.

In my app, I have an `Activity` which houses a `ViewPager` and an `xml` defined `FloatingActionMenu` constructed with the [following library](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button). The `ViewPager` contains a flexible number of `Fragments`, and inside each `Fragment` is a `RecyclerView`.

When clicked, the `FloatingActionMenu` expands into two buttons - one adds an extra page/Fragment to the `ViewPager`, the other adds an extra row to the `RecyclerView` on the page of the `ViewPager` the user is currently on. This feature works.

To hide the button, I use `addOnItemTouchListener` to the `RecyclerView` in my child fragments. Then, in `OnInterceptTouchEvent`, if the swipe gesture is large enough, I use a custom `Interface` to relay the event back to the hosting `Activity`, which conducts the animation to hide or show the button. Here is some of my code:

```
public class Categories extends ActionBarActivity implements
        View.OnClickListener,
        FloatingButtonInterface{

//...
// Final parameter is for the custom Interface
    mAdapter = new CategoriesViewPagerAdapter(mFragmentManager, allCategoriesCursor, this); 
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.categories_view_pager_pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    menuOriginalXPos = mFloatingActionsMenu.getX();
    menuOriginalYPos = mFloatingActionsMenu.getY();

//...
// onTouchEvent is the imaginative name for my custom Interface method.
    @Override
    public void onTouchEvent(int callBackID) {
        if (callBackID == FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_DOWN){
            if (mFloatingActionsMenu.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                Animation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
                        menuOriginalXPos, menuOriginalXPos, mViewPager.getHeight(), menuOriginalYPos);
                translate.setDuration(250);
                translate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                mFloatingActionsMenu.startAnimation(translate);
                mFloatingActionsMenu.setEnabled(true);
                mFloatingActionsMenu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else if (callBackID == FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_UP) {
            if (mFloatingActionsMenu.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                Animation translate = new TranslateAnimation(
                        menuOriginalXPos, menuOriginalXPos, menuOriginalYPos, mViewPager.getHeight());
                translate.setDuration(250);
                translate.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                mFloatingActionsMenu.startAnimation(translate);
                mFloatingActionsMenu.setEnabled(false);
                mFloatingActionsMenu.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my very straight forward interface:

```
public interface FloatingButtonInterface {

    public static final int MOTION_UP = 4;
    public static final int MOTION_DOWN = MOTION_UP+1;
    public static final int MOTION_NONE = 0;

    public void onTouchEvent(int callBackID);
}
```

Inside my `ViewPager`:

```
public class CategoriesViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "CategoriesViewPagerAd";

private Cursor mCursor;
private FloatingButtonInterface hideMenuInterface;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private boolean refreshItem = false;

public CategoriesViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor data, FloatingButtonInterface hideMenuInterface) {
    super(fm);
    mCursor = data;
    mFragmentManager = fm;
    this.hideMenuInterface = hideMenuInterface;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int categoryFragmentIdentifier =
            mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FilesDatabaseHelper.KEY_ID));
    CategoryFragment frag = CategoryFragment.newInstance(categoryFragmentIdentifier);
    frag.setOnTouchEvent(hideMenuInterface);
    return frag;
}
```

And finally, one of the `ViewPager` `Fragment`s:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements
        RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener,
        View.OnClickListener{
//...
private static final int TOUCH_SLOP=200;
//...
static CategoryFragment newInstance(int categoryIdentifier){
        CategoryFragment frag = new CategoryFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt(CATEGORY_ID, categoryIdentifier);
        frag.setArguments(bundle);

        return frag;
    }
//...
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(this);
//...
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                originalFingerPos = e.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (e.getY() - originalFingerPos > TOUCH_SLOP){
                    if (hideMenuInterface != null) {
                        hideMenuInterface.onTouchEvent(FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_DOWN);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "hideMenuInterface is null");
                    }
                } else if (e.getY() + TOUCH_SLOP < originalFingerPos ){
                    if (hideMenuInterface != null) {
                        hideMenuInterface.onTouchEvent(FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_UP);
                    } else {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "hideMenuInterface is null");
                    }
                }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The main problem I am having relates to the code I use to auto-hide the button when a user swipes up or down on the screen after a configuration change. If I change the screen orientation on a test device, when I attempt to hide the button with a swipe, some of the `Fragments` don't respond, and when I check `LogCat` I can see that `hideMenuInterface` is `null`. What can I do to address this? Why does it only effect a few of the fragments and not all of them? If I swipe to the final fragment in the ViewPager and then back again, the problem has resolved itself - likely because the fragment has been recreated.

Thanks for any insight you can offer! I only included code I felt would be relevant, as otherwise there'd be pages, but please ask if you think anything else would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer to this issue in the [Android Developer docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html). Button behaviour is far more reliable after following the instructions on this page.

---

**Edit:**

To expand on my previous answer, I applied the information from the documentation in the following way:

I altered `CategoryFragment` (the fragment that occupies each `ViewPager` item) by adding an inner `interface` called `FloatingButtonInterface`, and assigned a value to a `FloatingButtonInterface` variable during `onAttach()`:

```
public class CategoryFragment extends Fragment implements RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener {
//...
    private static final int TOUCH_SLOP = 200;
    private FloatingButtonInterface floatingButtonInterface;
//...
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        floatingButtonInterface = (FloatingButtonInterface) activity;
    }
//...
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(RecyclerView rv, MotionEvent e) {
        switch (e.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                originalFingerPos = e.getY();
                return false;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (e.getY() - originalFingerPos > TOUCH_SLOP) {
                    floatingButtonInterface.onTouchEvent(FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_DOWN);
                    return false;
                } else if (e.getY() + TOUCH_SLOP < originalFingerPos) {
                    floatingButtonInterace.onTouchEvent(FloatingButtonInterface.MOTION_UP);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
//...
public interface FloatingButtonInterface {

    public static final int MOTION_UP = MOTION_NONE + 4;
    public static final int MOTION_DOWN = MOTION_UP + 1;
    public static final int MOTION_NONE = 0;

    public void onTouchEvent(int callBackId);
}
```

The only other change is inside the `ViewPagerAdapter`. As `CategoryFragment` is responsible for assigning the interface, any code relating to this in the adapter can be removed, so that the adapter now looks like:

```
public class CategoriesViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "CategoriesViewPagerAd";

private Cursor mCursor;
private FloatingButtonInterface hideMenuInterface;
private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
private boolean refreshItem = false;

public CategoriesViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Cursor data) {
    super(fm);
    mCursor = data;
    mFragmentManager = fm;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(i);
    int categoryFragmentIdentifier =
            mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(FilesDatabaseHelper.KEY_ID));
    CategoryFragment frag = CategoryFragment.newInstance(categoryFragmentIdentifier);
    return frag;
}
```

Comment: You could also add an answer which explains the answer.It would help others reaching here.

Comment: @Droidekas Fair point. I've edited my answer to add more info.